# Sum of two squares in C

Tags: c

I have managed to get the sum of two squares, but it still doesnt work if for example 10: i need 9 and 1 ... My idea is to seacrch all the previous squares and find out how many will add up to the input, (max = 4) ... but im get stuck when duplicates occur and when i need to add 3 things... For 4 things I'm thinking of just adding an else statement. Any ideas/suggestions of how i can improve my algorithm?

Comment: Maybe attempt to find an answer by using 1 square, then 2 squares, then 3 squares, etc. This ensures you will always have the least number of squares used. More elegant and efficient solutions exist but this is what I imagine off the top of my head.

Comment: I would especially point out that in the else if you only check the cases of being 2*prevoussquare (2*9 in the example) and previoussqu+ preprev sq (9+4) - you must check ALL sums of all squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that you aren't supposed to use complex algorithm, I suggest you to loop through all the options, and check if the sum of squares make the number you need. While computing, you may also want to save the numbers in a global array, to simplify `getsquare`

Edit: since it's a nice problem, I wrote some code. (WARNING: I didn't check it)

```
int root[4];

int isqrt(int i) {return (int)floor(sqrt((double)i));}

// check if n is sum of s squares. assume s<=4
int canbesum(int s,int n) {
    if (s==0) return n==0;
    int i;
    for (i=isqrt(n);i;i--)
        if (canbesum(s-1,n-i*i)) {
            root[s-1]=i;
            return 1;
        }
    return 0;
}

int sumofsquares (int x) {
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<=4;i++) if (canbesum(i,x)) return i;
}
```

Comment: You indent like trying to fool everybody. You may want to take a look at this - http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle

Comment: That `for ... if` seems clear to me, but I will fix it. (If you meant to something else, please tell me)

Comment: What exactly does the root[4] do? is there a way to avoid it, cause i've never seen it before?

Comment: It's just an array. If you never saw an array (and probably a recursion), and supposed to not using arrays, don't copy my code, but write 4 nested loops.

Comment: will my 4 nested while loops be in the if statement in the for loop?

Comment: also what will be the contents of my nested loops check each case for s? (From 1 - 4)

Comment: no, just check every possible values. I suggest you to check first for 1 square, then for 2, etc... (Through it will make your code more complex). What exactly is your knowledge about C?

Comment: i see so for example if n=10 check, s=1, if not make s=2, and tht should work, since 1^2 + 3^2 = 10? As for knowledge, i tend to solve problems using recursion and iteration (for, while loops). Nothing with pointers or array's yet.

Comment: Well, if you know about recursion, you can use my code with some minor changes (or just learn the basic of arrays, and don't change anything.) and you see correct

Comment: `int root[4]`, in the most simple meaning, define 4 variables from the type `int`. If you can't use arrays. define 4 `int`s, and check s to know which one you should change.

Comment: Im confused how your boolean works? lets say n=10 and s=2 ... this should produce true(1). What exactly is the base-case thou. And soo i would define 4 global variables, and when you do root[s-1] that takes one variable and set it to s-1?

Comment: no. I said before that `int root[4]` mean that there is 4 variables. `root[s-1]` is the `s`th variable. (if you only want `sumofsquares`, and not care about `getsquare`, you cat remove this line.

Comment: Oh alrite, i understand now. for ur base case when s==0 why do you return n==0 not just 0 (since 0 is false?

Comment: Well, 0 is sum of 0 squares, so I have to check it.

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` is compare. I return the boolean value of `n==0`

Comment: is that the base case? lets say n = 4 and s =1, when we recurse in the for loop, we call canbesum(0,0)... how does the exactly return true(1), Im trying to trace your code...

Comment: yes. `canbesum(0,0)` return 1. when you call `canbesum(1,4)`, in the first iterate (when `i==2`), it check `canbesum(1-1,4-2*2)`, and since it return 1, it save 2 in the array, and return 1.

Comment: Where does it return 1? once canbe(0,0)is called it checks if(s==0) then return n==0... not 1 ? ..Or does it only recurse in the for-loop?

Comment: Alrite i finally get your some of square now, thank you sooo much!, so instead of array i defined 4 global variables as a1,a2,a3,a4... and i started like so;

Comment: inline `for (i=isqrt(n);i;i--)
    counter = counter + 1;
        if (canbesum(s-1,n-i*i)) {
        while (counter == 1){
        a1=i;
        }          
            return 1;
        }`

i get an error thou, im basically trying to use  counter (Which is also a global variable) and when counter =1 set a1 = i when counter =2 set a2 =i ... and so forthh ... is this a bad approach?

Comment: I guess that the line `counter=counter+1` should be out of the loop, and that you should reduce it back after the loop. (if not, you should wrap the body of the loop in `{}`). also, use `if`, not `while`. And finally, why do you need `counter` while you have `s`?

Comment: Your sum of squares code doesn't work for big numbers :S ... its seems to exceed CPU limit :(

Comment: yes. it's about O(2^4n), so it may take long time, but will work. (Unless you overflow the `int` bounds)

Comment: nvmm, i edited something that shouldnt have been there ... THANNKK YOU SOO MUCHH for your time !! :D

Comment: UMM i was just wondering i traced the case to s=3 and n=310 and then it went to s=0 and n=1 and wondering how tht is true? alsoo why do you decrement i, when the recursion is false? ... in other words how do we trace recursion when its in a loop, will there be loops in loops?

Comment: First, we check 17, and call `canbesum(2,21)`. since it's false, we continue the loop, and then 16, and after it fails to, we check 15, and call `canbesum(2,85)` . this call is true, and since then, we return true. that's the point of the loop - we check all numbers. not only the largest option. And yes. since you have function call in function call, and every function call have loop, you have loops in loops.

Comment: alrite, makes sense... how do we get to the next square of 9 ? Do we use (2,21) or (2,85) ?

Comment: Well, the loop begin from the square root of n, so if n is 21, we don't check 9. but if s is 2 and n is 85, we starting the check from 9, calling `canbesum(1,4)`, and then `canbesum(0,0)`.

Comment: Im trying to check how the function produces false, lets say (2,6) then we call (1,2) and then (1,5) ... (1,6) when will the decremeting stop? so i can get a boolean of 0(false?)

Comment: I dont get when the loop will terminate. if instead of 'i' and i use 'i>0' will that still work?

Comment: Yes. in that context, `i` mean `i!=0` .

Comment: How did you find out your program is about O(2^4n) running time?

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. If the input is `2^n` (so its length is `n`), And we check all possibilities until its square root, we do `2^(n/2)` checks. since we have 4 nested loops that do this, we have to power it by 4, to get `2^2n` . (My mistake was forgetting the square root part.)

Comment: Hey asaelr, i wondering if you could help me with a pointer question>?

Comment: Well, yes, but probably you should post it in a new question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7257/discussion-between-renato-fernandes-and-asaelr)